# What's the difference between request["data"] and request.form["data"]?

Tags: c#

On a postback with data as a type text both of these commands work.  Which one is preferable to use and why?

Comment: Thanks I searched for ["data"] specifically and didn't find anything.

Comment: Before you submit your question, SO suggests answers automatically that are similar; The duplicate (above) would have been one of them, as it is listed in related down the side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Request` indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) searches `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, and `ServerVariables`.

Using it is a recipe for security problems.
You should always know exactly where each value comes from; otherwise, attackers may be able to insert a different value somewhere else and bypass validation.

Comment: If I'm only passing back text that the user enters how could it introduce a security issue?

Comment: @StuckOnSimpleThings - if you expect it on the `Form` it can get overridden on the `QueryString`, for example.

Comment: Same difference as using PHP's `$_REQUEST` as opposed to `$_POST`.

Comment: So what should I use instead to for the text data I'm passing back?

Comment: @StuckOnSimpleThings: `Form` or `QueryString`, depending on how you're passing it.

Comment: Oh okay I understand.  I thought at first you were saying avoid both.  Yeah my element happens to be a div within the form, so I'll just use form.  It's more specific anyways so I imagined off the bat that it would be better. Thanks.